# Embed PHP in a Mediawiki page

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have been googling this for the best part of yesterday without any joy, so I'm here for the last hope for an answer before I give up!

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to embed a .php page in a MediaWiki page?
I was hoping for an extension of some sort or some other type of solution - I did see a post her somewhere during my search that suggested using a hook to make an extension - but I have absolutely no idea where to even start!

Essentially the problem I'm trying to solve is that I have a .php script that spits out the results of a couple of array queries, and I would like to present this directly on a MediaWiki page. I'm not bothered how, in an inline frame I assume..

Has anyone tried anything this and made it work?
Any pointers would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why not a simple Iframe ? You could pass values over the url. (Just an idea never tried). There is also an extension for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, as I suspected - as soon as I asked this question, I would find the answer!!

So here it is..

You need this extension:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:IframePage

After a little fettling I was able to embed a PHP script inside an inline frame on any WikiMedia page  I wanted. Genius!

Thanks to everyone who took a look, and I hope this will help someone else!
Cheers!